# How do i access the data from a dynamically added object

Tags: visual-studio-2013, basic

first time on this website, and i'm a bit short in time ...
So, it maybe so easy than i couldn't find somthing ....

I use a button to show a couple of textbox and other control, and give them the data of a object.

i have a ok button at the end and a event handler for it, and i would like to transfer the new data in control back in the object.

here is the code i use :

```
        Dim txtTitleM As New TextBox
        txtTitleM.AutoSize = True
        txtTitleM.Text = task.title
        pnlTask.Controls.Add(txtTitleM)
        indexY = txtTitleM.Size.Height + 10

        Dim txtDescriptionM As New TextBox
        With txtDescriptionM
            .AutoSize = True
            .Location = New Point(0, indexY)
            .Text = task.description
        End With
        pnlTask.Controls.Add(txtDescriptionM)
        indexY = indexY + txtDescriptionM.Size.Height + 10

        Dim cboCategoryM As New ComboBox
        Dim Item As Object
        For Each Item In cboCategory.Items
            With cboCategoryM.Items
                .Add(Item)
            End With
        Next

        With cboCategoryM
            .AutoSize = True
            .Location = New Point(0, indexY)
            .SelectedIndex = task.category
        End With
        pnlTask.Controls.Add(cboCategoryM)
        indexY = indexY + cboCategoryM.Size.Height + 10

        Dim chkDeadLine As New CheckBox
        With chkDeadLine
            .AutoSize = True
            .Location = New Point(0, indexY)
            .Text = "DeadLine"
            .Checked = task.deadline <> Nothing
        End With
        pnlTask.Controls.Add(chkDeadLine)
        indexY = indexY + chkDeadLine.Size.Height + 10

        If chkDeadLine.Checked Then
            Dim dtpDate As New DateTimePicker
            With dtpDate
                .AutoSize = True
                .Location = New Point(0, indexY)
                .Value = task.deadline.Date
            End With
            pnlTask.Controls.Add(dtpDate)
            indexY = indexY + dtpDate.Size.Height + 10
        End If

        Dim pnlBtnMod As New Panel
        pnlBtnMod.AutoSize = True
        'pnlBtnMod.Location = New Point(0, indexY + 10)
        pnlBtnMod.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
        grpTask.Controls.Add(pnlBtnMod)

        Dim btnOkMod As New Button
        btnOkMod.Text = "Ok"
        'btnOkMod.AutoSize = True
        'btnOkMod.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        pnlBtnMod.Controls.Add(btnOkMod)
        btnOkMod.Location = New Point(10, 0)
        AddHandler btnOkMod.Click, AddressOf clickOkModTask
```

and for the hendler :

```
Private Sub clickOkModTask(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim task As Task = findTask(sender)
        If Not task Is Nothing Then
            With task
                .title = txtTitleM.text
                .description = txtDescriptionM.text
                '.category = 
                '.deadline 
            End With
        End If
    End Sub
```

i know that the findTask(sender) doesn't work i have the trouble with the declaration of txtTitleM or any other control add dynamically. i can't make a "public Dim textbox As new textbox" ... so i don't know what i could use ...

Thank for your time, and your help if reply.

Comment: Could you add source code of `findTask`?

Comment: the code is hug because it's a class tp, i haven't do findtask, and it can't be use here because it a specific function who return the task object when you click on the display button include in the task. i will find a way after but i really need to find a way to access this control data

Comment: you have to navigate through visual tree to access to this textbox:
Sender is a button, get the parent which is a panel, and find textbox in its children collection...

Comment: i'm nor sure you understand what i need to do, here is m'y trouble 'code' .title = txtTitleM.text 'code' here the txtTitleM can't be accessed cause is declared in a function.

Comment: What is Task btw? It is not a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and where is the connection between `pnlTask` and `grpTask` Do they have same parent?

Comment: thank a lot for helping, but this starting to be complicated ... i will provide you the full code , click here : http://pastebin.com/AXysdTf2

Answer (score 0):

So:

1. `findTask` will return `pnlBtnMod` because `btnOkMod` is not part of `Controls` of `grpTask` it is `Controls` of `pnlBtnMod`

   - You have to call it again on `pnlBtnMod` to get `grpTask` because this is the root between Buttons and TextBoxes
2. Now you get `grpTask` but Controls array of Task does not contain your TextBox.

   - `grpTask` contains 2 Panel ( `pnlBtnMod`and `pnlTask`)
   - get the second panel from controls (`task.Controls(1) as Panel`)
3. Now you have the panel of TextBox-s

   - use index or give a Name (set `Name` Property) for TextBox to find them.

addon an ugly solution:

- set `Tag` property of `btnOkMod` in `displayTask` to these TextBox or array of TextBoxes
- and get these TextBox/TextBoxes in eventhandler directly